# group by sequence of events and get summary statistics for each sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have a data.frame with log of sequences of events. Here, sequence 1 is composed of event A, then B, then C, each starting at a specific timestamp (in seconds).

```
df=data.frame(id=runif(10, 1e6, 1e7), sequence = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4), event=c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C"), starts_at=c(20,22,24,20,30,20,21,23,20,40))
```

What I want is to group my data.frame by type of sequence (there are dozens of types, length 2 to 6): A->B->C or B->C, and then to get some results on those types. Desired output would be:

```
####                      sequence_type number.appearances mean.delay.between.events
####                    1           ABC                  2                   1.5 / 2
####                    2            BC                  2                        15
```

The last column "mean delay" would be a string composed of the mean diff time between successive events in a sequence: in ABC sequence, there is 1.5 seconds in average between A and B, and 2 between B and C.
I also thought of "spreading" each mean difference in a new column diff.1, diff.2..., but seems complicated since sequence have different lengths. Though i'm open to different ways of presenting this information..

So far I've come up with:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(sequence) %>% arrange(starts_at) %>% summarise(sequence_type = paste0(event, collapse="")) %>% group_by(sequence_type) %>% tally
```

I didn't find how to achieve the second part. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Do you always have alternating "ABC" and "AB" as `sequence` increases? So for example, `sequence = 1` has `event = "A", "B", "C"`; `sequence = 2` has `event = "A", "B"`; `sequence = 3` has the same events as `sequence = 1`; `sequence = 4` has the same events as `sequence = 2`.

Comment: Oh no it can really be anything (i edited the question); there are dozens of types of sequences, of lengths ranging from 2 to 6 for most of them. There is not really an order in my raw data.frame, everything is shuffled that's why i use 'arrange'

Comment: I think this is an opportunity to use `rle` from base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not bee the elegant solution you would get with `dplyr` but I think is general enough that it would work with your real data.
First you just need to get the corresponding sequence of each row of your data, that is `ayuda_seq`

```
library(zoo)
df=data.frame(id=runif(14, 1e6, 1e7), sequence = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,5), 
              event=c("A", "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "B", "C","A","B","C","D"), 
              starts_at=c(20,22,24,20,30,20,21,23,20,40,20,22,21,15))
ayuda_seq = sapply(df$sequence, function(x) paste0(df[df$sequence == x,3],collapse = ""))
```

and then you just loop through the unique sequences and generate the sub sequence by each 2 elements.

```
vec_means = NULL
for(x in unique(ayuda_seq)){
  data_temp = df[ayuda_seq == x,]
  diff_temp = diff(data_temp$starts_at)
  temp_sub = apply(rollapply(data_temp[,3],FUN = paste0,width = 2),1,paste0,collapse = "")
  mean_temp = aggregate(diff_temp,by = list(temp_sub),mean)
  if(all(!duplicated(temp_sub))){
    averages = paste0(mean_temp[,2],collapse = " / ")
  } else{
    averages = paste0(mean_temp[match(temp_sub[duplicated(temp_sub)],mean_temp[,1]),2],collapse = " / ")
  }
  vec_means = c(vec_means,averages)
}


df_res = data.frame(sequence_type = unique(ayuda_seq),
                    number.appearances = as.numeric(table(ayuda_seq)/nchar(unique(ayuda_seq))),
                    mean.delay.between.events = vec_means)
```

the variable `temp_sub` will have the different combinations within the original string you are looping. In the case of `"ABC"` there is a possible combination of "CA" which is not taking in consideration because it is unique.

Comment: thanks, it indeed gives the expected output on the fake data; but for some reason if I shuffle this data or add a new sequence of a new type, it doesn't give the right answer..?

Comment: @agenis what do you mean by shuffling the toy data? any way someone added a different answer hope it works. If not post a data that's closer to your real one and I'll see if a can fix the code.

Comment: i mean if you reorder randomly the  rows of the fake data, it should work the same...

Comment: OK I see what you mean. The code assumes the variable sequence is order correctly like in your data sample. If it is not it won't work and it also assumes that all the sequences (ABC....) are not unique, but that's an easy fix in the code.

Comment: ok I see. it's not a problem, because i'm not interested in unique sequences anyway :-)

Comment: Ok so i'm 95% sure the code will work if your variable sequence is order correctly

Comment: Right. I accept your answer. In case the data is not ordered proporly we just begin with df = df %>% arrange(sequence, starts_at)

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but it works

```
tmp<-df %>% group_by(sequence) %>% dplyr::arrange(sequence, starts_at) %>%  dplyr::mutate(seq_row_num=dplyr::row_number(), lead_starts_at=dplyr::lead(starts_at, n = 1)) %>% base::as.data.frame()
tmp<- tmp %>% dplyr::group_by(sequence) %>% mutate(max_seq_len=max(seq_row_num)) %>% base::as.data.frame()
tmp$seq_len_id<- paste0(tmp$sequence, tmp$max_seq_len)
tmp$next_seq_val<- tmp$seq_row_num + 1
tmp$next_seq_val<- base::ifelse(tmp$next_seq_val >= tmp$max_seq_len, tmp$max_seq_len, tmp$next_seq_val)
tmp_seq_labels<- stats::aggregate(tmp$event, list(tmp$seq_len_id), paste, collapse='')
tmp<- base::merge(tmp, tmp_seq_labels, by.x="seq_len_id", by.y="Group.1")
colnames(tmp)[which(colnames(tmp)=="x")]<- "seq_group"
tmp$within_group_step<-"ZZ"


tmp$within_group_step<- base::ifelse(tmp$seq_row_num != tmp$max_seq_len, substr(tmp$seq_group, start = tmp$seq_row_num, stop =tmp$next_seq_val), tmp$within_group_step)
tmp$within_step_by_group_id<- paste0(tmp$seq_group, tmp$within_group_step)
tmp$time_diff<- 0
tmp$time_diff<- base::ifelse(!is.na(tmp$lead_starts_at), tmp$lead_starts_at - tmp$starts_at, tmp$time_diff)

res<- stats::aggregate(time_diff ~ within_step_by_group_id + seq_group + within_group_step, data=tmp, FUN=mean)
drops<- grep(pattern = "ZZ", x = res$within_step_by_group_id)
if(length(drops)>=1){
  res<- res[-drops,]
}


colnames(res)<- c("Full_Group_Pattern", "Group_Pattern", "Sub_Group_Pattern", "Mean_Time_Difference")
res<- res %>% dplyr::group_by(Group_Pattern) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Number_of_Appearances=n()) %>% base::as.data.frame()
```

Here is the result:
[image]